# CSS overlay and position in corner

Tags: css

[image]

Both the black and white box are divs. I want to position the black div overlayed on top of the white box and moved to the left corner.

I know to overlay is z-image but how would I postion the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just position it absolutely: http://jsfiddle.net/zkDft/